# Identify unknown component

Tags: identification

I am trying to identify the red cylindrical component from the board.
There are 5 of these on the board.

Can anyone identify the manufacturer part number?
[image]

Comment: Maybe trimpots. Could you possibly wipe some of the grime off them so the markings are readable?

Comment: Not possible at the moment. WIll update again once I get a chance to wipe it.

Comment: please show a clear picture of the component that is well lit ... pictures of components in shadows are not useful

Comment: I read 10k(omega) on the one on the top left.

Comment: I don't see a red cylindrical component. Everything is black :)

Comment: They may all be the same sort of component but they may all have different values.

Answer (score 1):

These are "trimpots".  Also known as potentiometers, or variable resistors.
[image: Trimpots]

(image source: Now defunct ebay listing)
(New image source found by SamGibson:  https://www.radio741.com/46050-4m7-47mohm-potentiometer-trimmer-piher-qty-10.html)

If you clean them carefully, you can probably see their value written on the outer radius.